# replace the text in html tag with another text

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice">
   <span class="PageText_L483n">
    <font class="text colors_text">
     <b><span class="PageText_L335n">Our Price</span>: </b>
    </font>$101.82Amber
   </span>
</font>
```

i want to change 101.82 in the above html code to the value from the following span tag.

```
<span class="csqft_price">96.96</span>
```

That is 101.82 should be replaced by 96.96 dynamically using jquery.That is any value in span tag having  `class="csqft_price"` sholud be replaced in the above font tag where the value is 101.82

Please advise.

Comment: I can't understand the question. 
Do you want any span tag with the class "csqft_price" to have the number inside replaced with 96.96 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very simply: you should move this 101.82 in a `span tag` and use this below script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('.PageText_L483n').html();
    $('.PageText_L483n').children().remove();
    var text2=text.replace($('.PageText_L483n').text().trim(),$('.csqft_price').text());
    $('.PageText_L483n').html(text2);    
});
```

**EDITED**

Comment: how can i move 101.82 in span tag. Please help

Comment: just include another `span` inside your nested `<span class="PageText_L483n">` like 
`<font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n"><font class="text colors_text"><b><span class="PageText_L335n">Our Price</span>: </b></font>$<span id="testspan">101.82</span>Amber</span></font>
`

Comment: no the above html that i have pasted is hardcoded i cannot change it. Is there any way through jquery that i can add span tag to it.

Comment: This is not correct, they can't use #csqft_price. As mentioned, the code is hard-coded and they can't modify it. I tried that code on JSFiddle and it didn't seem to work?

Comment: i guess its working now, i just modified a bit and he can use `#csqft_price` why not ? or else i didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

To add a element using jQuery you can use append. See this link [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't very clear so I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var span = $('.pricecolor span');// this includes another font and span tag..
   var oldSpan = span.find('font'); //so we can add the Our Price again...
   span.find('font').remove(); //remove the font part so we can replace the number
   span.html(oldSpan.html() + span.html().replace(/\d+.?\d+/, '<span class="csqft_price">96.96</span>'));
});
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cde3w/

The code isn't very pretty but it might lead you in the right direction...